# Fast swinging or rocking

Tags: infant, behavior, development, crying

My little one just turned 2 months old. When swinging in the swing or when I am rocking him he likes to be swinging fast and rocking fast...I don't mean normal fast he likes to go FAST! Is this normal and why do you think he might like this? He cries until I go fast and then settles right down. I am not sure why. He does seem to have colic and cries more than the average baby. Any one have this happen with their child??

Comment: Hi, Sherry, and yes, someone recently asked a similar question. Here's a link: [How strongly can a 1mo be rocked?](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14557/). How is your little one growing? Sometimes this indicates that the baby is hungry.

Comment: FYI, if you feel a question is a duplicate (as this seems to be), please feel free to flag or vote to close as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's safe to say that ALL kids enjoy swinging and rocking.  Certainly it's a time tested way to help infants get calmed down and get to sleep.  In fact it's a recommended technique by [The Happiest Baby on the Block Book](http://www.happiestbaby.com/) (which my the way has an extensive discussion on colicky babies - highly recommend this book for you).  The author says that swinging switches on a baby's "calming reflex".  It's one of several techniques he advocates, so if you feel you're doing it too much, you might want to look at those.  Swaddling and lower back massages were my "daddy tricks".

My two kids certainly enjoyed fast swinging and rocking when they were infants.  My daughter in particular loved fast swinging and spinning and rocking... like to an abnormal extreme; my son was more into being bounced and walked.  They both enjoyed being in a mechanical rocker, as well as more intense manual rocking.  The important thing to keep in mind with very young infants is that their brain, inner ear, neck muscles, and stomach valves are still under development, so if you're too aggressive or do it for too long of a period I suppose it could risk things like fainting, vertigo, vomiting, etc.  But I think so long as you're supporting their neck and don't tip them upside down, the baby should be fine.

I've seen mixed opinions from doctors and other parents on whether the motion is helpful in developing the child's sense of balance.  I'm convinced it does, and felt with my own kids that it helped them be more active sooner, and walk earlier than average.  But who knows; every kid is unique and has unique needs.

My daughter is now 3 years old, and after returning from Disneyland we asked what rides she liked the best:  "I like the train that goes on the hills!"  (The rollercoaster in Toon Town - the only rollercoaster she's tall enough to go on.  Once she learned such a thing existed, that's all she wanted to do, over and over again, like 15-20 times.)  Prior to that her favorite was the spinning tea cups.  So perhaps you and your son have this joy to look forward to!  :-)